No provider offers [AES_256, GCM, NoPadding] for AES key of class android.security.keystore2.AndroidKeyStoreSecretKey and export format null
I've tried to encrypt data with SecretKey like below:
KeyGenParameterSpec keyGenParameterSpec = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                "alias", KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                .setKeySize(256)
                .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
                .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
                .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                .setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(30)
                .build();
KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, "AndroidKeyStore");
keyGenerator.init(keyGenParameterSpec);
SecretKey secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES_256/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
byte[] doFinal = cipher.doFinal(inputBytes);

But fails with the following error: No provider offers [AES_256, GCM, NoPadding] for AES key of class android.security.keystore2.AndroidKeyStoreSecretKey and export format null
Any advice?

In Java/Android you never specify the AES key length in the Cipher.getInstance call. Just use AES. If the key you provide in the init call has 256 bits = 32 bytes then AES 256 is used.
